# How do I access my Windows partition?

Tags: hard-drive

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my HP G62-453 TU Laptop. I cannot access the contents of my hard disk partition E.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu along side windows?

Answer (score 21):

This is assuming that you have installed Ubuntu in a dual-boot setup alongside Windows.

Open the terminal, and type `df -h`

This will show you the drives mounted as well as occupied and free space.  Look for the filesystem mounted at /

This is your Linux partition.

Now type `cd /dev/`, then `ls`.

You should see several entries like

```
sda sda1 sda2 sdb sdb1 sdg sdg1
```

Each sd* is a storage volume, and the number is the partition.  The above example has two partitions (`sda1`, `sda2`) on the boot drive and two external drives available(`sdb`, `sdg`).  You need to mount the partition before accessing it. On my system, I have four partitions set up on my boot drive

```
sda sda1 sda2 sda3 sda5
```

where `sda5` is my Linux partition, `sda2` is the Windows partition and `sda3` is the common storage partition.

To mount the drives right now, type `sudo mount /dev/sdaX`, where X is the number of the partion to mount.

To automatically mount the drives on boot, install mountmanager by typing

```
sudo apt-get install mountmanager
```

This installs an application that allows you to configure the auto-mounting of drives upon boot.  Open it up, and in the filetree select the sd* partition available, then enter the mount point for the partition.  I use the `/media/` folder as the base mount point, then you specify the mount folder.

For example, my `/media/` folder looks like

```
Library/ Storage/ Windows/
```

Once you've done this, you apply the changes via `Partition -> Apply`

This should make your partition visible in both Natutilus and the command line in `/media/`

Comment: After doing `cd /dev/; ls` and seeing the list of storage volumes, how can we determine which is the Windows partition? One way is to type `cat /proc/partitions`, and try to guess by the relative sizes of partitions, but is there a better way?

Comment: Why don't you run `fdisk -l /dev/sda` and search for Windows partition in output?

Answer (score 3):

Under Linux their is no partition E:/  
Open your personal folder, in the left panel it should show the diffrent partions found on your system. These could have a name you gven them or just something like '200gb filesystem'

Answer (score 1):

[gDisk screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Q7C.png)

The gDisk application part of the Ubuntu 15.04 apps set allows you to edit partitions. But it also displays enough info per partition for you to tell what is what, where it is, etc.
And it also has a convenient "Mount button", just below the selected partition, it looks like a standard "Play" button.