# Can't Find Windows's partitions in Linux

Tags: dual-boot, drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access Windows partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148474/how-to-access-windows-partition)

I have made dual boot system with Ubuntu and Windows 7 (Preinstalled given by manufacturer on Laptop). I am not able to find my windows drives (C:, D: drives) in Ubuntu. How can I access Window's drives in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is different than windows, you can find your drives c:, d: or anything in Places, You have to just keep your mouse at left side at TOP panel, find your drives in `Places` menu. You may find drives name like 50 Gb, 100 Gb or anything like that. If you want give paricular name like System to C:  drive Entertainment to D: drive. Reboot your system with windows and rename drive names by going to my computer, click particular drive, `press F2` and rename drive. Reboot machine with  Ubuntu you will find your drives with Names in `Places`.

Comment: Patel, If you have understood the question properly can you please edit it and make more clear about what OP is looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I have the type of set up you describe working and used the steps from this guide:-

http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony

..basically you free up space on the Windows side then create a shared NTFS partition using GParted.