# Installed Ubuntu over windows

Tags: windows, files, data-recovery

I need to get those windows files. Please let me know whether there is any procedure to get those windows files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu) or [Recovering broken or deleted NTFS partitions](https://askubuntu.com/q/775579). (For the much less serious situation of installing Ubuntu *alongside* Windows so the system remains intact, but some problem causes Windows not to boot and one wants to recover files before solving that problem, see [How do I access my Windows partition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/148474))

Answer (score 0):

When you overwrote Windows with Ubuntu, you also changed the file format. Luckily, you can recover files from an NTFS partition with a Ubuntu Live CD/USB. This [page](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13706/recover-deleted-files-on-an-ntfs-hard-drive-from-a-ubuntu-live-cd/) gives a rundown of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

if you have windows currently working then use easybcd.
or if u have currrently ubuntu working then use grub2

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2
install and backup ur current boot to pendrive.

or else use livecd of windows to recover boot loader.

be carefull u face a hardware issue if u plug out power from it while working