# Post dual install, How to view the files on c:/ drive?

Tags: 12.10, windows-7

After using the windows installer, and running now ubuntu, i need t know ...

How to view the files on c:/ drive [it contains the windows installation + documents and the ubuntu also]

I selected the ubuntu space to be 10GB, is that enough? and if not .. how to increase it!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post with info about your windows partition:
[Using a Windows partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148474/how-do-i-access-my-windows-partition)

If you are just playing around and either don't have lots of video/sound files, you'll be fine with 10GB IMHO.

As to how to increase the space you have allocated- that depends on how you installed it, WUBI, VirtualBox or dual boot.

Comment: thanks for the link, it's really informative. I've installed ubuntu using the wubi.exe within win7, it was really smooth and direct installation and it was done in about 10-15 minutes. but i'm now considering changing to ubuntu and i'd like to use more space for it.   Thanks again.